# Игровое поле в виде таблицы

Tags: android

**Хочу сделать:**

Игровое поле в виде таблицы(4*4 например).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В одной ячейке будет кружочек, который пользователь сможет перетаскивать из одной ячейки в другую. Перетаскивать так: тапнул на кружок, держишь и тащишь в нужную ячейку.

Поле должно быть условное, т.е. не должно быть видно разметки.

**Вопросы:**

1.С помощью чего лучше сделать поле ? (я думаю можно попробовать с помощью TabelLayout)
2.Как сделать перетаскивание кружочка по клеткам ? Сам кружочек - обычная картинка.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите делать это через View компоненты, то у меня для вас плохие известия. Чтобы не было ерунды на экране, то делайте своё **View**, но советую вам наследоваться не от View, а от SurfaceView, можете почитать [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html) про кастомные View, а [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/surfaceview.php) хороший пример реализации данного класса

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "ерунды на экране" ? Разница View и Surface view как я понял в том, что в просто вью надо самому постоянно обновлять экран, а в сюрфейс вью - само в цикле обновляется. П.с. с сюрфейс вью не работал, прочел на просторах инета об этом.

Comment: Вы не совсем правильно поняли различия. Самая главная разница в том, что View выполняется исключительно в главном потоке, поэтому, если вы пишите какую-то игру, то это может быть накладно для системы, при частых изменениях в View объекте, а при использовании  SurfaceView вы выполняете все действия в другом потоке, и когда канва будет готова для отрисовки, вы посылаете команду на отрисовку. Что же по поводу "Разница View и Surface view как я понял в том, что в просто вью надо самому постоянно обновлять экран, а в сюрфейс вью - само в цикле обновляется.", то тут вы неправильно поняли.

Comment: и та и та может сама обновляться при определённых действиях, просто у View нужно вызывать метод **invalidate()**, у SurfaceView этого метода вызывать не нужно, там всё замешано на том, что как канва будет подготовлена, вы просто вызовите метод для разблокировки канвы и её отрисовки, но всё это реализуется в самой View или SurfaceView, а не внешней посылкой комманд

Comment: Что же по поводу ерунды на экране, то вам придётся липить целую кучу костылей для данной реализации по средствам View компонентов, т.к. вечно размеры будут не те, поддёргивания, ОЧЕНЬ  БОЛЬШАЯ нагрузка на сам аппарат, это всё ни к чему хорошему не приведёт, поверьте. А когда вы реализуете это сами, то вы сэкономите на нагрузке и времени построения проекта и ваша игра будет работать без лишних затупков и тормозов.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения! Я никогда не делал своих вью компонентов еще.. Вы уже реализовывали какие-то свои вью компоненты ?

Comment: Да и поверьте, это ни разу не сложно. Если голова есть, то можно и за день разобраться. А как научитесь, то поймёте, что вы Брюс всемогущий, которому не нужны стандартные въюхи и вы можете закодить любую штуку, которую только придумает ваша фантазия

Comment: Вот почитайте тут оффициальную документацию на эту тему, тут 4 урока, но на английском, там всё от и до написано **http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/index.html**

Comment: Самая большая проблема при создании View компонентов, это их рисование, тут уже нужно будет почитать уроки о канве и что и как рисуется, но тут тоже ничего трудного, главное голова и фантазия

Comment: спасибо! гайд почитаю. А часто приходится в работе делать свои вью компоненты ?

Comment: "Самая большая проблема при создании View компонентов, это их рисование" рисование компонентов это в каком плане ? Где их рисуют ?

Comment: Вы уроки почитайте по рисованию на сайте www.startandroid.ru Что же по поводу как часто, то тут всё от вас зависит, если вы видите, что стандартных компонентов не хватает, то пишите свои, но можно пошерстить github на наличие уже готовых библиотек с готовыми въюхами, но в случае игр врятли кто-то сделал нужную вам библиотеку для вашей задачи

Comment: View/SurfaceView и кастомніе компоненты мы выяснили) Возможно, у Вас есть какие-то советы по тому как реализовать что мне надо ?

Comment: Даже не знаю. Ваша задача довольно просто. Нарисовать клеточное поле, шар и двигать его довоььно просто. Реализовать можно какими угодно способами. Просто продумайте логику и всё получится